# Foreach implementation on splitting a string into array and filling into a list

Tags: linq

I have a string of email addresses something like :

> string str = abc@gmail.com;ghf < ghf@gmail.com >;xyz < xyz@gmail.com>

Now i wanna do something like this

```
List<string> test = new List<string>();
        Regex.Split(to, ";").ToList().ForEach(x => x.Split(new char[] { '<', '>' }).Select(y => y != "<" || y != ">"));
```

Now how do i Fill only email addresses like abc@gmail.com , ghf@gmail.com and xyz@gmail.com into the list test in single linq query ?

Comment: Your code sample won't actually do anything useful - it creates a list  and calls `Select` on it, but that's not going to affect `test`...

Comment: Try to get out of the habit of using `ToList().ForEach(...)`, it's a terribly abused construct with no real benefit whatsoever.  Just use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah I know both your parts . Actually  I was trying to get rid of foreach but dint knew how . How Jon I know that code really doesnt do anything . I wasnt actually getting the clue how to do that so I tried my best how to get upto there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = str.Split(';')
              .Select(m => Regex.Replace(m, "([^<]+)<([^>]+)>", "$2")
              .Trim()).ToList();
```

Comment: @Rapheal can you please tell how this regex exression worked ? I m not too familier with regex a little explanation wd b sufficient :) How ever the result I got isnt upto the mark yet but I can modify your code to my need if I can understand what your Regex does :) .However it was quite close to result what I actually desired :)

Comment: @Joy 1. (Everything before char `<`) + `<` + (Everything before char `>`) + `>`. Replace all that by the content of second expression (Everything before char `>`). Then Trim to remove white spaces. Hope it's (a little bit) more clear.

Comment: @Joy and I tested with the given example, and got a fine result. You may give a "non working example", maybe.

Comment: I gave string str= Qa5  <qa5@gmail.com>;Qa5  <qa5@gmail.com>;abc@gmail.com which gave me result as result = qa5@gmail.comqa5@gmail.com, abc@gmail.com

Comment: @Joy well tested with your string, and I get a list of 3 elements qa5@gmail.com,qa5@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com ... Isn't it what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
var test = Regex.Split(to, ";").ToList().ForEach(x => x.Split(new char[] { '<', '>' }).Select(y => y != "<" || y != ">"));
```